# React - Testing Card component (Ant Design)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, antd

I'm having an issue testing components using Card component (Ant Design). Every time I run my tests I encounter messages like this :

> Error: Uncaught [RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded]
>
> The above error occurred in the  component

Does anybody know about this issue ? I tried to find something on Ant Design git but the few pages I found were not in english and do not seems to be realted to my issue.

I tried to test directly the Ant Design component (Card) with a mount ([https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/card/**tests**/index.test.js](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/card/__tests__/index.test.js)) but I encouter the same error...

Here is my second test with only Ant Design component :

```
import React from 'react'
import { mount } from 'enzyme'
import { Card } from 'antd'

describe('Card', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    jest.useFakeTimers()
  })

  afterAll(() => {
    jest.useRealTimers()
  })

  it('should still have padding when card which set padding to 0 is loading', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<Card title="xxx">xxx</Card>)
  })
})
```

I have an Enzyme adapter in my setup. Here I just wanted to show you how simple my code is however I can't product any result...

Somebody can help ?

Comment: why are you stubbing timers? Is the issue reproducible with no fake timers?

Comment: It's the same without timers

Comment: Yes it is, I just copied from the Ant design doc